# Fastest way on iOS 7+ to get CVPixelBufferRef from BGRA bytes

Tags: ios, video, textures

What is the fastest way on iOS 7+ to convert raw bytes of BGRA / `UIImage` data to a `CVPixelBufferRef`? The bytes are 4 bytes per pixel in BGRA order.

Is there any chance of a direct cast here vs. copying data into a secondary storage?

I've considered `CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes` but I have a hunch it is copying memory...

Comment: CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes is even slower than memcpy...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `CVPixelBufferCreate` because `CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes` will not allow fast conversion to an OpenGL texture using the Core Video texture cache. I'm not sure why this is the case, but that's the way things are at least as of iOS 8. I tested this with the profiler, and `CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes` causes a texSubImage2D call to be made every time a Core Video texture is accessed from the cache.

`CVPixelBufferCreate` will do funny things if the width is not a multiple of 16, so if you plan on doing CPU operations on `CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress`, and you want it to be laid out like a `CGImage` or `CGBitmapContext`, you will need to pad your width higher until it is a multiple of 16, or make sure you use the CVPixelBufferGetRowBytes and pass that to any `CGBitmapContext` you create.

I tested all combinations of dimensions of width and height from 16 to 2048, and as long as they were padded to the next highest multiple of 16, the memory was laid out properly.

```
+ (NSInteger) alignmentForPixelBufferDimension:(NSInteger)dim
{
    static const NSInteger modValue = 16;
    NSInteger mod = dim % modValue;
    return (mod == 0 ? dim : (dim + (modValue - mod)));
}

+ (NSDictionary*) pixelBufferSurfaceAttributesOfSize:(CGSize)size
{
    return @{ (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA),
              (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferWidthKey: @(size.width),
              (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferHeightKey: @(size.height),
              (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferBytesPerRowAlignmentKey: @(size.width * 4),
              (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferExtendedPixelsLeftKey: @(0),
              (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferExtendedPixelsRightKey: @(0),
              (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferExtendedPixelsTopKey: @(0),
              (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferExtendedPixelsBottomKey: @(0),
              (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPlaneAlignmentKey: @(0),
              (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: @(YES),
              (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: @(YES),
              (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferOpenGLESCompatibilityKey: @(YES),
              (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey: @{ @"IOSurfaceCGBitmapContextCompatibility": @(YES), @"IOSurfaceOpenGLESFBOCompatibility": @(YES), @"IOSurfaceOpenGLESTextureCompatibility": @(YES) } };
}
```

Interestingly enough, if you ask for a texture from the Core Video cache with dimensions smaller than the padded dimensions, it will return a texture immediately. Somehow underneath it is able to reference the original texture, but with a smaller width and height.

To sum up, you cannot wrap existing memory with a `CVPixelBufferRef` using `CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes` and use the Core Video texture cache efficiently. You must use `CVPixelBufferCreate` and use `CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress`.

Comment: I wonder why that is. Maybe it's unrelated. CVPixelBufferCreate definitely will create a buffer with the optimal alignment etc., but maybe there is "correct" alignment to pass to CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes -- as long as your raw bytes array *is* with that alignment :) This way you'll also skip the initial memcpy. Though if you malloc'd those raw bytes to begin with... then why not "malloc" with CVPixelBufferCreate or even better, CVPixelBuferPool.

Comment: If you didn't pad what to a multiple of 16? I was asking whether it's possible to create the buffer yourself and use CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes, as long as you create a "good" buffer.

Comment: Create with bytes never creates a valid open gl texture unfortunately.

Comment: Are you sure? Are they using texSubImage2D (rather than texImage2D) to replace the whole texture?

Comment: I believe it was texsubimage2d. The cpu impact was bad.